# Facebook share button not working inside Fancybox

Tags: fancybox, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

I got the code for the Facebook share button code right from facebook, it is as this:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://example.com/item/sharefb/47"></div>
```

While on a regular page, it works fine. It renders it assyncrhonously and for each item on the page working great.

But inside a fancybox ajax call, the button simply won't work. Facebook API will not process it, and the `div` will not turn into facebook's iframe full of stuff.

Any hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parse the button after opening the box:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse

Comment: Worked like a charm! :)